# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous' via c# console app

Tags: c#, authorization, ntlm

How to get authorized with scheme 'NTLM' via console c# app?

I try to connect to web-service (I have url with wsdl file).
So, i create service reference, add this address and press Go!

But I receive an error:

```
 The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://webserver/service.php?wsdl'.
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The     authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using that generates this error.

Comment: I havent any code yet- i try to get service refernce via VS 2012

Comment: Is webs3 the name of your machine?  Is this a local webservice?  Is the webserver configured for anonymous access?

Comment: i rename it to webserver. No, it is not local machine,it is test webserver configurated to NTML authorization.

Comment: Try reviewing this. [Troubleshooting Service References:Error Accessing a Service over a Remote Desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628645.aspx)